# Why can't the result of a modulo operation be used in an if statement directly?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, modulo

I'm doing a challenge from a book and it's asking me to create a loop that counts down from 20 to 0 and has me print a message for each number. However, it's asking me to print out a special message for each number divisible by 5. I have seen certain examples including this one:

```
if (number%5==0)
{
    //your code here
}
```

I get what the modulo is doing, but why does this code have `==0` after it? For example, why not just code it like this:

```
if (number%5)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: The condition inside the if statement must be true. So, "number%5" must be equal to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `number%5` is an integer between 0 and 4, while `number%5==0` is a boolean. Unlike languages like C/C++ where integers can be considered booleans (0 -> false, 1 -> true for example), in C# the condition of an if must be a 'real' boolean.

(Even if C# let you use an integer in an if condition, your suggested change to the code is incorrect. The former piece of code would run your code if number%5 is 0, the latter piece of code would run your code if number%5 is NOT 0.)

EDIT: As Eric Lippert says in the comments, an alternative to using a `bool` in an `if` condition is to use something that implements `implicit operator bool` as a cast or implements operators `true` and `false`, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx . But as far as I can tell, no primitives besides `bool` satisfy either of these.

Comment: I believe the design decision was made to solve the problem you identified (incorrect logic, that is).

Comment: @Matthew I think another problem is that in systems where integers are considered bools, all non-zero are True and zero is False. So you could have a value that boolan evaluates to True such as 2) then do 2 == True and be surprised to find you get False!

Comment: I see, so the condition has to be either true or false. It can't be an integer. For example, if I say "if(x=12)", the x=12 is either a true or false statement. X either equals 12 or it doesn't. True or false. Makes sense.

Comment: @Chris Smith I hope for your sake you meant to type x==12, not x=12!

Comment: @Matthew, more specifically, `if (x = 5)`. Won't compile (because `x=5` is not a boolean value), in C#. Will compile, but produces unexpected results, in some other languages.

Comment: @Patashu Yes, I'm so sorry =) I did mean x==12. That's a big error on my part. x=12 is giving x a value of 12 which is not a true or false statement. x==12 is saying x is equal to 12. Phew, bad mistake. EDIT: (int x = 12) would be giving x a value of 12. I really need to think before I type.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good but there is a small mistake. Technically C# does not require that the condition of an `if` be of type `bool`. Rather, it requires that *either* (1) the condition is *implicitly convertible* to `bool` or (2) that the condition expression implements an `operator true` that produces a `bool` from the given expression. And incidentally, this is also true of `while` and all the other constructs that branch based on a Boolean value.

Comment: @EricLippert Cool! Not something I've messed with before.